# C++ alternatives for libjpeg?

Tags: c++, libjpeg

Are there any alternatives for libjpeg? This library requires complicated installation routines, but I cannot find another jpeg library. Those I managed to find (such as CImg) require libjpeg anyway.

Comment: Since this is a yes/no question (not asking for recommendations), I suppose it's borderline on-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes: [`stb_image`](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) is a single-file, header-only image loader that supports most common JPEG files.